# Show up optionpane with text when one of the button cliced

Tags: java, swing

I want to add a pop up when one of the buttons is clicked

Here is the code:

This is the subclass

```
public class Pajero extends Mobil implements ActionMobil{


    @Override
    public void kecepatan() {
        System.out.println("Mobil ngegas");
    }

    @Override
    public void rem() {
        System.out.println("Mobil ngerem");
    }

    @Override
    public void belokKiri() {
        System.out.println("Mobil belok kiri");
    }

    @Override
    public void belokKanan() {
        System.out.println("Mobil belok kanan");
    }

    @Override
    public void percepatMobil() {
        System.out.println("Mobil sekarang berjalan lebih cepat");
    }

    @Override
    public void perlambatMobil() {
        System.out.println("Mobil sekarang berjalan lebih lambat");
    }   
}
```

This is the main class

```
public class Main {

    private final ActionMobil setir;

    public Main(ActionMobil Setir) {
        this.setir = Setir;
    }

    public void TampilTipeMobil(){
        setir.tampilTipe();
    }

    void drive() {
        setir.kecepatan();
        setir.rem();
        setir.belokKiri();
        setir.belokKanan();
    }

    void percepat(){
        setir.percepatMobil();

    }

    void perlambat(){
        setir.perlambatMobil();
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
```

and this is the frame class

```
package KendaraanDua;

/**
 *
 * @author Marsu
 */
public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Frame
     */
    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private Frame(Pajero pajero) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jOptionPane1 = new javax.swing.JOptionPane();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        BtnPercepat = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BtnPerlambat = new javax.swing.JButton();
        PopUp = new javax.swing.JOptionPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Kontrol Mobil");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Kontrol Pada Mobil");

        jLabel2.setText("- Mobil ngegas");

        jLabel3.setText("- Mobil ngerem");

        jLabel4.setText("- Mobil belok kiri");

        jLabel5.setText("- Mobil belok kanan");

        BtnPercepat.setText("Percepat");
        BtnPercepat.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BtnPercepatActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        BtnPerlambat.setText("Perlambat");
        BtnPerlambat.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BtnPerlambatActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(141, 141, 141)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(96, 96, 96)
                        .addComponent(BtnPercepat)
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(BtnPerlambat))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))))
                .addContainerGap(103, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(PopUp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(62, 62, 62))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(BtnPerlambat)
                    .addComponent(BtnPercepat))
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addComponent(PopUp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void BtnPercepatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        /** Shows ControlMobil.percepat(); on optionpane when its clicked **/
    }                                           

    private void BtnPerlambatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        /** Shows ControlMobil.perlambat(); on optionpane when its clicked **/
    }                                            

    private void drive() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void percepat() {

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("---Penggunaan pengkontrolan pada Mobil---");
        System.out.println();



        System.out.println("---Kontrol pada Mobil---");
        Main ControlMobil;
        ControlMobil = new Main(new Pajero());
        ControlMobil.drive();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("---Action---");
        ControlMobil.percepat();
        ControlMobil.perlambat();

        System.out.println("");

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton BtnPercepat;
    private javax.swing.JButton BtnPerlambat;
    private javax.swing.JOptionPane PopUp;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JOptionPane jOptionPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

mobil class

```
package Kendaraan;
  public abstract class Mobil{
    public String merkMobil;

    public void tampilTipe(){
        System.out.println("Pajero");
    }
}
```

actionMobil class

```
package Kendaraan;


public interface ActionMobil {
    public void kecepatan();
    public void rem();
    public void belokKiri();
    public void belokKanan();

    public void percepatMobil();
    public void perlambatMobil();

    public void tampilTipe();
}
```

As you can see, I want to show the  `ControlMobil.percepat();` on the `BtnPercepat` and have it show up on the optionpane.

Comment: Can you post your Mobil and ActionMobil ? That would make it easier

Comment: okay, i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

For what i think you are trying to achieve you need to change several things.
The option pane showing comes in the method you commented out assuming that the object is a class field, in the Frame.java:

```
Main controlMobil2 = new Main(new Pajero());

private void BtnPercepatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        /** Shows ControlMobil.percepat(); on optionpane when its clicked **/

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, controlMobil2.percepat());
}
```

This forces the percepat on main to return a string, Main.java:

```
String percepat(){
        return setir.percepatMobil();

}
```

Which in its turn forces the interface to return the String to be printed instead of writing it to the console:

```
public interface ActionMobil {
    ...
    public String percepatMobil();
    ...
}
```

As well as the pajero class:

```
public class Pajero extends Mobil implements ActionMobil{
    ...

    @Override
    public String percepatMobil() {
        //System.out.println("Mobil sekarang berjalan lebih cepat");
        return "Mobil sekarang berjalan lebih cepat";
    }

    ...  
}
```

As a side note the naming conventions state that variables should start in lower case.

Comment: It Works! Thanks a lot for the help.